# Blender Renderman - Transparent plastic

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, renderman-render-engine

I have an object, where I wanted to have specific parts that looks like a transparent plastic.

So I have used the primitive variables to adjust the part that I want to be transparent, and the others that I don’t want to.

I’m using a `PxrLMPlastic`. But after I tweak all the settings, the material stays like a non-transparent plastic.

The presence parameter is the only one to make something, but it acts like an Alpha channel. When it sets to `0`, the material is not visible anymore.

Is there any tips on how to achieve a transparent plastic in Renderman?

Comment: Since the material is non transparent, could you broaden the scope of this question by simply requesting a transparent material setup?

Comment: it's not possible to turn transparent the PxrLMPlastic?